# Conditionally insert different substring depending on column name

Tags: r

An example of mydataframe is this:

```
datatimedf = data.frame(time_start_1 = c('Apr 2005', '2004', '2000', 'Mar 2011'), time_end_1 = c('Apr 2012', '2011', 'Oct 2001', '2012'))
```

Some values in these columns have year and month, others have only year.  If a cell has only the year (month is missing), I want to insert a month value.

The month value to insert depends on which column it is:  If it's in the `time_start_1` column, insert "Jan" and if it is in the `time_end_1` column insert "Dec".

Example of expected output:

```
datatimedf = data.frame(time_start_1 = c('Apr 2005', 'Jan 2004', 'Jan 2000', 'Mar 2011'), time_end_1 = c('Apr 2012', 'Dec 2011', 'Oct 2001', 'Dec 2012'))
```

Comment: I'm confused, is `time_start_1` supposed to be "previous start time" or the "current start time"? Which column are you comparing to which? Also, can you provide a dataset with more rows so that it is clearer what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your intent right, this should work as long as you have character columns and not factors (hence the `stringsAsFactors = F`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

        datatimedf = data.frame(time_start_1 = c('Apr 2005', '2004', '2000', 'Mar 2011'), time_end_1 = c('Apr 2012', '2011', 'Oct 2001', '2012'), stringsAsFactors = F)                        

       datatimedf %>% 
               mutate(time_start_1 = ifelse(str_detect(time_start_1, "[[:alpha:]]"), time_start_1, paste0("Jan ", time_start_1)))  %>% 
               mutate(time_end_1 = ifelse(str_detect(time_end_1, "[[:alpha:]]"), time_end_1, paste0("Dec ", time_end_1)))
```